# Creating SQL composite Key Logic

Tags: sql, database-design, database-normalization, composite-primary-key

I am laying out a database design and have a question around creating a composite ID.  The part of the database I am stuck on is a "rounds" table.

The goal of the database is to store results of MMA fights to allow for statistical analysis.

In every fight there are three judges to score a round.  I think my best route is to create a "rounds" table that is unique to every "fightID_FK"+"fighterID_FK"+"judgeID_FK"+"roundNum".  My thought is to create a composite of those 4 columns to create one PK. The only other column in that table will be "roundScore" which is the score that a judge, gives a fighter, in a fight, in round 1,2,3,4 or 5.

Is this the best way to go about this?  Are there any factors I am not considering?

Comment: A composite key does *not* mean 4 columns concatenated into 1. A composite key is a key that spans multiple columns. You should add a key constraint that includes all 4 columns.

Comment: Yes I understand, I was concatenating the columns above just to show what I was thinking.  I guess my question is - if there is an inherent flaw or downside to adding a key constraint across 4 rows vs just having an auto increasing column that identifies each of these rows?

Answer (score 1):

Your 4-column "natural" key is a good idea. Adding a ("surrogate") id column doesn't help constrain to valid values; you should declare the key whether or not you add an id. And when another table has a FK on the id to the original table and has any of the 4 columns and a value for the id and those columns must also appear in the original table then you still need a constraint in the referencing table which would have been unnecessary if you just had a FK to the 4 columns and no id. (And in most DBMSs that constraint is unlikely to be declaratively enforced, unlike the FK.)

*PS* Justifying that a table is normalized to a certain normal form requires showing that it has certain properties or following certain procedures. It isn't enough to only show that a particular column set is a candidate key (ie unique with no smaller unique subset).

*PPS*

Even though your table is in 6NF you should enforce a constraint that is due to an embedded join dependency.

There is typically more than one fighter in a fight. So when a row appears with a given round and one fighter, there has to be a row with the same fight, judge and round but another fighter. There can be more than one judge of a fight. If there are rows with two judges of the same fight, fighter and round, and another row with one of those judges and the same fight, fighter and another round, then there has to be another row with the other judge with that fight, fighter and round. So although your four columns do form a candidate key for your five-column table and your table is in 6NF, your table is subject to "anomalies" that aren't addressed by normalization via decomposition to projections.

Consider the tables Particpated(fighterID,fightID), Judged(judgeID,fight_ID,judgeID) & Round_of(roundNum,fight_ID). The projection of your table on fightID, fighterID, judgeID & roundNum is always Participated JOIN Judged JOIN Round_of. Unfortunately most DBMSs don't allow you to enforce this constraint declaratively.

Comment: I think I can follow what you are saying but don't quite agree.  Yes there are multiple fighters and judges for any one fight.  However, the combination of a fight/fighter/judge/round is unique.  and the score that judge gives that fighter, for that round, in that fight is also unique.

Are you saying that because I would be entering that combination of data, twice for each round that it isn't following normalized rules?

Comment: You're right that although this table is subject to an *embedded* dependency with associated update anomalies they aren't those that normalization would remove. Please see my edited message.